# Mongo Error of top operator any other logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Getting error of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: unknown top level operator: $ne while executing following code, is there any other logic to do not equal to is_main false or alternate null ?

```
     functionAlternate=(mainTitles,dd,Title_Alternate,Title_Details)=>{
  if (conn == null) {
    conn=  db.connectToDB();
 }
  return  new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      var cModel = conn.model(constants.collectionName.project, project_model.projectSchema,constants.collectionName.project);  
      cModel.find({ $or : [ {$ne: {"is_main":false},  }, {'alternate':null }] }).then(d => {
        let result = insertProjects(mainTitles,dd,Title_Alternate,Title_Details);
        resolve(true);
        return result;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: $or operator should be used like this: {$or: [{"key1": "value1"}, {"key2": "value2"}]}

Comment: @ShikharTandon I want to use along with $ne can you help me out placing it in code? Error is `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $ne`

Comment: Can you post the code with $ne operator present. I want to see how and where you are using the operator in the code

Comment: @ShikharTandon any update?

Comment: You need to specify the $ne operator inside, rather than outside

Change: $ne: {"is_main":false} -> "is_main": { $ne: false}

Answer (score 0):

please check find query like this. it may work.

```
{ $or : [ {"is_main":{$ne:false}}, {'alternate':null }] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the find query with this:

```
{$or: [ {"is_main":{$ne:false}}, {"alternate":null}] }
```

Also, can't also replace the `{"is_main":{$ne:false}}` with `{"is_main": true}`

The `$or` is a logical operator and the value for it needs to be and array of key-value objects
`$ne` is a conditional operator and can be used for one comparison at a time